# How to validate Hour and Minutes that came from a Swing textBox?

Tags: java, parsing, swing

I have a window that contains a HH:mm time TextField in it, in **24 hours** format

I need to validate if the user entered any non valid hour, like 28:00, 99:00, 24:01.

What's the best and simpler way to do that ?

some code below of what is currently doing that job wrong and giving errors in date parsed.
Today I get an random hour and an user hit 99:99 in that text field.

This code is not mine, but I gotta fix it.

I am stuck with it, tried to validate as a String is useless, and I cannot find a nice way to make it a Date without having to put year, month, etc... too.

Please forget about the return -1 instead of throwing an exception this is old code and this cannot be changed.

to help understand :
Statics.hF2               = SimpleDateFormat (HH:mm)
this.cmpHora.getText()    = Is the field with the value
Statics.df_ddmmyy         = Another date format
Statics.m2ms              = converts minutes to milliseconds

//CODE

```
public long getDataEmLong ()
{
   try
   {
      Calendar hour= Calendar.getInstance();
      new GregorianCalendar().
      hour.setTime( Statics.hF2.parse( this.cmpHora.getText() ) );
      return Statics.df_ddmmyy.parse( this.cmpData.getText() ).getTime() + Statics.m2ms( hour.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) * 60 ) + Statics.m2ms( hour.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) );
   } catch ( Exception e )
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return -1;
   }

}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this in your class, and perform the `validateTime` method from inside your junk code.

```
public boolean validateTime(String timeString) {
    if (timeString.length() != 5) return false;
    if (!timeString.substring(2, 3).equals(":")) return false;
    int hour = validateNumber(timeString.substring(0, 2));
    int minute = validateNumber(timeString.substring(3));
    if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24) return false;
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60) return false;
    return true;
}

public int validateNumber(String numberString) {
    try {
        int number = Integer.valueOf(numberString);
        return number;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `validateNumber()` function is broken. If you pass in "-1" the result will be the same as the error case. This isn't an issue in the way you are using it, but without a better name or documentation, it could cause issues in the future.

Comment: @unholysampler:  Fine.  Change the -1 in validateNumber to Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, it just makes it less likely to occur. The exception is there so you don't have to encode an error state into the functions return type. This is a case where you are catching the exception before you can properly handle it. If you got rid of `validateNumber()` and put `valueOf()` in `validateTime()`, you can handle the exception properly and return false.

Comment: @unholysampler:  We're just going to agree to disagree.  I did properly handle the exception in validateNumber.  I returned a number not in the range of 0 - 59 that would fail upon further testing.  Now, if you want to generalize validateNumber futher, you and / or cfontes are free to do so.

Comment: That is my point in the first place. It works for it's current usage. But, from the function signature, it is not clear that that generalization will need to be done in the future. A more descriptive function name or moving the try/catch is all that is needed to potentially save someone debug time down the road when the method does not validate all numbers.

Answer (score 4):

[Regular expressions to the rescue](http://xkcd.com/208/):

```
public boolean validTime24(String time) {
    return time.matches("^([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$")
}
```

This will validate the format of the string. Then you can parse out the time from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFormattedTextField with proper Date or Time Format set. The field will return you proper values.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can use DateTimeFormatter:

```
public boolean validate(String time) {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
            timeFormatter.parse(time);
            return true;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```